# how to get two table row together

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how to show two table row together 
and my code is wrong it is showing blank result may be some mistakes in code please help me to fix this issue

thanks

i have two table

1) flats

```
------------------------------------------
flatsno | buildingname| flattype | status |
------------------------------------------
001    | building1   | Double   |  empty |
002    | building1   | single   |  empty |
003    | building1   | Double   |  empty |
004    | building1   | Double   |  empty |
005    | building2   | Double   |  empty |
```

2)contract

---

```
flatno | buildingname| flattype | status |
------------------------------------------
001    | building1   | Double   |  rent  |
002    | building1   | single   |  rent  |
005    | building2   | Double   |  rent  |
```

and i want result like that

result

```
------------------------------------------
flatno | buildingname| flattype | status |
------------------------------------------
001    | building1   | Double   |  rent  |
002    | building1   | single   |  rent  |
003    | building1   | Double   |  empty |
004    | building1   | Double   |  empty |
005    | building2   | Double   |  rent  |
```

and im using this code but it is showing blank result

```
<?php


    $dbserver = 'localhost'; 
    $dblogin  = 'root';
    $dbpassword = '';  
    $dbname = 'building';

    //opening connection
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbserver, $dblogin, $dbpassword, $dbname);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }


function formatMoney($number, $fractional=false) {
    if ($fractional) {
        $number = sprintf('%.2f', $number);
    }
    while (true) {
        $replaced = preg_replace('/(-?\d+)(\d\d\d)/', '$1,$2', $number);
        if ($replaced != $number) {
            $number = $replaced;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $number;
}       
$a=$_POST['from'];


    echo "<div id='non-printable'><table align='center' class='sortable' border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
    echo "<tr><th>Flatno</th><th>Buildingname</th><th>floor no</th><th>flatclass</th><th>flattype</th></tr>";

    //opening connection
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `flatsno`, `buildingname`, `status`, `flattype` FROM `flats`  WHERE `flatsno` AND `buildingname` = '$a' ORDER BY `flatsno` ASC") or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
    while($student = $result->fetch_assoc())
    { 
       $subresult = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `contract` WHERE `flatno` = '".$contract['flatno']."' AND `buildingname` = '$a'") or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
        if($row = $subresult->fetch_assoc())

        {
            echo "<tr>"; 
            echo '<td>' . $row['flatsno'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['buildingname'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['flattype'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $row['status'] . '</td>';
            echo "</tr>"; 

        }
        else
        {
            echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>' . $contract['flatno'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $contract['buildingname'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $contract['flattype'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['status'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td></td>';


            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
            echo '</table>';

mysqli_close($mysqli); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get the required result using only 1 query (instead of 2 queries which you have currently used). Try using this query:

```
SELECT f.flatsno, f.buildingname, IFNULL(c.status,f.status) as status, f.flattype 
FROM `flats` f LEFT JOIN `contract` c
ON f.flatsno = c.flatno AND f.buildingname = c.buildingname
WHERE f.buildingname = "building1"
ORDER BY f.flatsno ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that with only the SELECT below and loop to iterate over the resultset solve the problem.

```
select f.flatsno, f.buildingname, c.flattype , c.status 
from flats f
     inner join contract c on (f.flatsno = c.flatsno )
where   <<  tradudor and desired order >>
```

I hope it is usefull

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is to have the data of both tables combined in a new table, right?
If not, you should do that anyway, because your data is not normalized. In most cases you want to have your database in at least third normal form. If you don't know what I'm talking about, it's a topic I highly recommend you read about.

Anyway, you can achieve above mentioned like this:

```
create table new_table like flats;

insert into new_table
select
f.flatsno, f.buildingname, f.flattype, coalesce(c.status, f.status)
from
flats f
left join contract c on f.flatsno = c.flatno and f.buildingname = c.buildingname;

select * from new_table;
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43af75/2/0).